# Failed unmount from GUI

Tags: mount, vfat

I am developing a script which provides mount only specific USB Storage.

First I blocked automount feature from /etc/udev/rules.d/85-no-automount.rules by adding

```
blockrule="SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ENV{UDISKS_AUTO}:="0", ENV{UDISKS_IGNORE}:="1";
```

It works properly

Secondly, mount command runs in a script having root permission.

```
mount -t vfat -o umask=0000 /dev/sdb1 /media/AA;
```

It also work properly, standart user, administator who is logged read write USB.

Problems occur when a user want to unmout USB drive from GUI

[image: Unmount from GUI]

[image: Error1]

When i added fstab following line

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/AA vfat rw,umask=0 0 0
```

Message is changed to:

[image]

/media folder has:

```
(/media)
 ∴ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 root root  4096 Ağu 21 11:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root root  4096 Ağu 20 09:33 ..
drwxrwxrwx   3 root ossec 4096 Oca  1  1970 AA
drwxr-x---+  2 root root  4096 Ağu 20 15:34 deneme
drwxr-x---+  2 root root  4096 Ağu 21 10:29 root
```

I thought the problem is owner of mounted dictionary

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 root ossec 4096 Oca  1  1970 AA
```

So I tried the change mount command to

```
mount -t vfat -o uid=1004,gid=1004 umask=0000 /dev/sdb1 /media/AA;
```

/media folder was changed to:

```
(/media)
 ∴ ll
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   6 root   root   4096 Ağu 21 11:42 .
drwxr-xr-x  24 root   root   4096 Ağu 20 09:33 ..
drwxrwxrwx   3 deneme deneme 4096 Oca  1  1970 AA
drwxr-x---+  3 root   root   4096 Ağu 20 15:22 aagin
drwxr-x---+  2 root   root   4096 Ağu 20 15:34 deneme
drwxr-x---+  2 root   root   4096 Ağu 21 10:29 root
```

Owner of mounted dictionary is changed to

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 deneme deneme 4096 Oca  1  1970 AA
```

But it is not solve problem. I also changed

```
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/ org.freedesktop.udisks.policy
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/ org.freedesktop.udisks2.policy
```

inside of these files, every node has:

```
<defaults>
  <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
  <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
  <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

**How can standart user unmount from GUI?**

Thanks